# bash curl command not found on OS X. Where can I find it?

Tags: bash, macos, curl, homebrew

I have no idea what I am getting myself into, I am very new to programming and trying to learn on my own.  I am trying to install homebrew with `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)` and this the outcome is *"-bash: curl: command not found"*

I have been searching Google but can't seem to find anything to help me.  when I type `which curl` it just goes to the next line of terminal as if I just opened terminal...
I have xcode installed with command line tools installed, and even downloaded reinstalled it in case something was wrong with it.
Not that it matters but the reason I am attempting to install homebrew is it is needed for libsodium which is needed for dnscrypt.

When I type `curl-config` it gives me available values for OPTION include:

```
  --built-shared says 'yes' if libcurl was built shared
  --ca        ca bundle install path
  --cc        compiler
  --cflags    pre-processor and compiler flags
  --checkfor [version] check for (lib)curl of the specified version
  --configure the arguments given to configure when building curl
  --features  newline separated list of enabled features
  --help      display this help and exit
  --libs      library linking information
  --prefix    curl install prefix
  --protocols newline separated list of enabled protocols
  --static-libs static libcurl library linking information
  --version   output version information
  --vernum    output the version information as a number (hexadecimal)
```

Then I try any of of those like `curl --version` and it does the same curl command not found

Comment: It just sounds like you don't have `curl` installed. What operating system are you using? EDIT: you mentioned Xcode, so I'm guessing you're on a Mac. I'm afraid I'm no help there in particular, but that's what "command not found" means, generally.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/95855/how-to-install-curl-on-osx-with-brew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative you can use `wget`:

```
ruby -e "$(wget -qO - 'https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go')"
```

Answer (score 65):

Install curl by:

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

Comment: when I try sudo apt-get install curl  it returns"sudo: apt-get: command not found"

Comment: Ahh - I just saw Mike & Sean's comments - I'm afraid that I am not much on a Mac either, but I did find this link which may or not help: http://www.vettyofficer.com/2013/06/how-to-install-curl-in-mac-os-x.html

Answer (score -2):

I finally installing homebrew to work by changing to the zsh terminal - just type zsh when you open the terminal (maybe there is a better way). I didn't directly install curl, just xcode.